# loading valid json file in python throws error JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

I have a json file, that is valid according to json linter, that looks like this:

```
[{
    "Device": {
        "BNCode": "BN2003612",
        "DeviceID": 3700,
        "ModelName": "2004c",
        "VariantName": "2004c",
        "supplier": {
            "SupplierCode": "ALCATEL",
            "SupplierID": 3,
            "SupplierName": "Alcatel",
            "created_at": "2019-08-14T14:47:00",
            "last_updated_by": "",
            "updated_at": "2019-08-14T14:47:00"
        }
    },
    "MarketPlayer": {
        "DetailedMarketPlayer": "WestCom",
        "MarketPlayerID": 3968,
        "MarketPlayerName": "Amazon"
    },
    "PriceUrl": "",
    "Sales_Price": {
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "EUR": 6.658333333333334e+001,
        "local_currency": 6.658333333333334e+001
    },
    "ScreenshotUrl": "",
    "Source": "OFFICIENCE",
    "TimeStamp": "Date"
}, {
    "Device": {
        "BNCode": "BN2003833",
        "DeviceID": 3800,
        "ModelName": "Nokia 130",
        "VariantName": "Nokia 130 8MB LTE DS",
        "supplier": {
            "SupplierCode": "HMD",
            "SupplierID": 45,
            "SupplierName": "Hmd",
            "created_at": "2019-08-14T14:47:00",
            "last_updated_by": "",
            "updated_at": "2019-08-14T14:47:00"
        }
    },
    "MarketPlayer": {
        "DetailedMarketPlayer": "MediaMarkt",
        "MarketPlayerID": 3815,
        "MarketPlayerName": "MediaMarkt"
    },
    "PriceUrl": "",
    "Sales_Price": {
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "EUR": 2.665833333333333e+001,
        "local_currency": 2.665833333333333e+001
    },
    "ScreenshotUrl": "",
    "Source": "OFFICIENCE",
    "TimeStamp": "Date"
}]
```

To import the json file into python I am using the following code:

```
import json
with open('prices_json.txt') as f:
    data_dict = json.load(f)
```

I am getting the error: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).

When I use the json.loads function I get the error: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper.

EDIT: I think I noticed that the JSON is getting "fixed" when copying the data from the file directly into here and formatting it as code. Thats why you guys can not reproduce my error.  I attached this image of how the code actually looks like, it seems there is more whitespace and I would assume that is causing the issues so any idea on how to fix it is welcome.
[image]

Link to the file: https://file.io/yKw7tp

Comment: Use `data_dict = json.loads(f.read())`

Comment: I just tried your code in `Python 3.7`. It didn't throw any error.

Comment: @Codelt getting the same JSONDecodeError as before :/

Comment: @Tim Are you sure that your .txt file contains same content as above ?

Comment: Whitespace is not the problem. JSON is not affected by that.

Comment: Why not just copy paste the code you posted in the question into your text file and run the script on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the above `prices_json.txt` file then you should be getting it worked. I have tested it and it is working. See this [repl](https://repl.it/repls/GrubbyNextAmpersand).

You can also try passing complete file as string to `json.loads()` method to convert it into json object.

```
data_dict = json.loads(f.read())
```

**EDIT**

The actual cause of the problem was the file itself. When i tried to print it using `f.read()`, it gave output like this:

```
ÿþ[ {

         " D e v i c e " :   {

                 " B N C o d e " :   " B N 2 0 0 3 6 1 2 " ,

                 " D e v i c e I D " :   3 7 0 0 ,

                 " M o d e l N a m e " :   " 2 0 0 4 c " ,

                 " V a r i a n t N a m e " :   " 2 0 0 4 c " ,

                 " s u p p l i e r " :   {

                         " S u p p l i e r C o d e " :   " A L C A T E L " ,

                         " S u p p l i e r I D " :   3 ,

                         " S u p p l i e r N a m e " :   " A l c a t e l " ,

                         " c r e a t e d _ a t " :   " 2 0 1 9 - 0 8 - 1 4 T 1 4 : 4 7 : 0 0 " ,

                         " l a s t _ u p d a t e d _ b y " :   " " ,

                         " u p d a t e d _ a t " :   " 2 0 1 9 - 0 8 - 1 4 T 1 4 : 4 7 : 0 0 "

                 }

         } ,

         " M a r k e t P l a y e r " :   {

                 " D e t a i l e d M a r k e t P l a y e r " :   " W e s t C o m " ,

                 " M a r k e t P l a y e r I D " :   3 9 6 8 ,

                 " M a r k e t P l a y e r N a m e " :   " A m a z o n "

         } ,

         " P r i c e U r l " :   " " ,

         " S a l e s _ P r i c e " :   {

                 " C u r r e n c y C o d e " :   " E U R " ,

                 " E U R " :   6 . 6 5 8 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 e + 0 0 1 ,

                 " l o c a l _ c u r r e n c y " :   6 . 6 5 8 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 e + 0 0 1

         } ,

         " S c r e e n s h o t U r l " :   " " ,

         " S o u r c e " :   " O F F I C I E N C E " ,

         " T i m e S t a m p " :   " D a t e "

 } ,   {

         " D e v i c e " :   {

                 " B N C o d e " :   " B N 2 0 0 3 8 3 3 " ,

                 " D e v i c e I D " :   3 8 0 0 ,

                 " M o d e l N a m e " :   " N o k i a   1 3 0 " ,

                 " V a r i a n t N a m e " :   " N o k i a   1 3 0   8 M B   L T E   D S " ,

                 " s u p p l i e r " :   {

                         " S u p p l i e r C o d e " :   " H M D " ,

                         " S u p p l i e r I D " :   4 5 ,

                         " S u p p l i e r N a m e " :   " H m d " ,

                         " c r e a t e d _ a t " :   " 2 0 1 9 - 0 8 - 1 4 T 1 4 : 4 7 : 0 0 " ,

                         " l a s t _ u p d a t e d _ b y " :   " " ,

                         " u p d a t e d _ a t " :   " 2 0 1 9 - 0 8 - 1 4 T 1 4 : 4 7 : 0 0 "

                 }

         } ,

         " M a r k e t P l a y e r " :   {

                 " D e t a i l e d M a r k e t P l a y e r " :   " M e d i a M a r k t " ,

                 " M a r k e t P l a y e r I D " :   3 8 1 5 ,

                 " M a r k e t P l a y e r N a m e " :   " M e d i a M a r k t "

         } ,

         " P r i c e U r l " :   " " ,

         " S a l e s _ P r i c e " :   {

                 " C u r r e n c y C o d e " :   " E U R " ,

                 " E U R " :   2 . 6 6 5 8 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 e + 0 0 1 ,

                 " l o c a l _ c u r r e n c y " :   2 . 6 6 5 8 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 e + 0 0 1

         } ,

         " S c r e e n s h o t U r l " :   " " ,

         " S o u r c e " :   " O F F I C I E N C E " ,

         " T i m e S t a m p " :   " D a t e "

 } ]
```

You need to use `utf-16` as encoding parameter while opening the file to fix the problem.

Using `json.loads` method:

```
import json
with open('prices_json.txt',encoding="utf-16") as f:
    data_dict = json.loads(f.read())
print(data_dict)
```

Using `json.load` method

```
import json
with open('prices_json.txt',encoding="utf-16") as f:
    data_dict = json.load(f)
print(data_dict)
```

Comment: But that was not the issue. I tried with `json.load(f)`. It worked. No errror.

Comment: @SukumarRdjf I also tried the same. Check this [repl](https://repl.it/repls/GrubbyNextAmpersand). Both method worked fine. I guess the OP is using a different json file.

Comment: @Codelt I added an edit after trying it again with the posted json here. Seems like the formatting gets fixed when coping the data into here, my bad.. I added an image with how it actually looks like when opening the file.

Comment: @Tim Whitespace is not the actual problem. If you could provide us link to that file, we can probably test what exactly is wrong.

Comment: @Codelt Im sorry for the confusion added a link to the file at the bottom

Comment: @Tim The link you posted in your question is giving *error 404*

Comment: @Tim You can try using `f.read().replace("\n","").replace("\t","")`, it will replace all tab s and new line characters from the file.

Comment: @Tim Can you use any other file uploading site, i tried your latest link it is showing file not found

Comment: @Codelt weird, maybe those links expire after a time, I redid it and the new link is working for me, I will test your replace method now